# Reading Atiyah's article

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-bundles, vector-fields

I'm reading Atiyah's article about his homonymous theorem but cannot figure out some of the notations he used. I'm not very familiar with algebraic geometry, so I thought I could ask here for some help: the article to which I refer is (["Convexity and commuting hamiltonians"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.396.48&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

- There, he talks about "Negative normal bundle" (Proof of Lemma 2.1). I know what a normal bundle is, but I don't know what a negative normal bundle actually is;
- at the very beginning he defined "almost periodic vector fields" as those that generate a torus action (and I didn't understand in which sense can a vectorial field generate an action (probably by exponential?)); referring to that, in (Lemma 2.2) he said that the almost periodic vector field "$X_\phi$ is the set of the fixed points" of the action generated by $X_\phi$ (How can a vector field be a set of points?);
- At page 6, he used the following notation: "$\pm\phi|N$" and "$\pm f_{n+1}|N$" where $\phi$ and $f_{n+1}$ are real valued functions. What does it mean (he said that $\pm\phi|N$- for example - has $Z\cap N$ as a non-degenerate critical manifold, so I guess they both are subsets of $N$)?

Comment: Not a full answer to all. The first one sounds like a virtual vector bundle which you can find in the so called "K-Theory" which seems to be related. Any vector field generates a so called flow, which acts diffeomorphically on the manifold. Roughly speaking a flow sends a point on the manifold where the vector field is aiming at at that position. Maybe the point returns (then it is periodic), maybe it is kept in a small tube around a closed curve (then it is almost periodic). From what I read the notation $\pm\Phi\mid N$ probably means the restriction of $\pm\Phi$ to $N$.